# Hsqldb rename duplicates of item names with same parent

Tags: python, google-drive-api, hsqldb, uno

I wrote a LibreOffice / OpenOffice extension that allows access to these Google Drive files.

To do so, I use a Hsqldb 2.4 database, [script file is accessible at:](https://github.com/prrvchr/gDriveOOo/blob/master/gDriveOOo/hsqldb/vnd.google-apps.script)
https://github.com/prrvchr/gDriveOOo/blob/master/gDriveOOo/hsqldb/vnd.google-apps.script

The LibreOffice / OpenOffice UNO API does not handle duplicate file names (such as under a file system), while Google Drive offers this possibility.

To work around this problem, I created four View ('ChildUri', 'IdentifierUri', 'ItemUri' and 'Uri') allowing me to build a new name of the form: CONCAT (name, ~, position) for the second and following doublon, position being their position in the GROUP BY clause...

```
CREATE VIEW PUBLIC."ChildUri" ("Id","Name","Parent") AS SELECT "I"."Id","I"."Name","C"."ItemId" FROM PUBLIC."Items" AS "I" JOIN PUBLIC."Children" AS "C" ON "I"."Id"="C"."ChildId"  WHERE "I"."Trashed"=FALSE

CREATE VIEW PUBLIC."IdentifierUri" ("Idx","Name","Parent") AS SELECT ARRAY_AGG("I"."Id" ORDER BY "I"."DateCreated","I"."Id"),"I"."Name","C"."Parent" FROM PUBLIC."Items" AS "I" JOIN PUBLIC."ChildUri" AS "C" ON "I"."Id"="C"."Id" GROUP BY "I"."Name","C"."Parent"

CREATE VIEW PUBLIC."ItemUri" ("Id","Name","Length","Position","Parent") AS SELECT "C"."Id","I"."Name",CARDINALITY("I"."Idx"),POSITION_ARRAY("C"."Id" IN "I"."Idx"),"I"."Parent" FROM PUBLIC."ChildUri" AS "C" JOIN PUBLIC."IdentifierUri" AS "I" ON "C"."Name"="I"."Name" AND "C"."Parent"="I"."Parent"

CREATE VIEW PUBLIC."Uri" ("Id","Name","Uri","Parent") AS SELECT "I"."Id","I"."Name",CASEWHEN("I"."Position"=1,"I"."Name",INSERT("I"."Name", LENGTH("I"."Name") - POSITION('.' IN REVERSE("I"."Name")) + 1,0,CONCAT('~',"I"."Position"))),"I"."Parent" FROM PUBLIC."ItemUri" AS "I"
```

It works well, but drastically lacks speed when calling the 'selectChild' procedure, it takes 10 seconds to execute, whereas before only some second.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PUBLIC."selectChild"(IN USERID VARCHAR(100),IN ITEMID VARCHAR(100),IN URL VARCHAR(250),IN MODE SMALLINT,OUT ROWCOUNT SMALLINT) SPECIFIC "selectChild_1" LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA NEW SAVEPOINT LEVEL DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 BEGIN ATOMIC DECLARE TMPCOUNT SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;DECLARE RESULT CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT "Title","Size","DateModified","DateCreated","IsFolder",CASEWHEN("IsFolder",CONCAT(URL,'/',"Id"),CONCAT(URL,'/',"Uri"))"TargetURL",FALSE "IsHidden",FALSE "IsVolume",FALSE "IsRemote",FALSE "IsRemoveable",FALSE "IsFloppy",FALSE "IsCompactDisc" FROM PUBLIC."Child" WHERE "UserId"=USERID AND "Parent"=ITEMID AND("IsFolder" OR "Loaded">=MODE)FOR READ ONLY;CALL "countChild"(USERID,ITEMID,MODE,TMPCOUNT);SET ROWCOUNT=TMPCOUNT;OPEN RESULT;END
```

I admit that it exceeds my skills, and turns to you for help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index to improve SELECT query speed on a table. The SELECT in the procedure needs an index such as the following if it is not already a FOREIGN KEY

```
CREATE INDEX "ChildIndex" ON "Child"("Parent", "UserId")
```

Answer (score 1):

fredt, what a pleasure it's you who answers ... Can not find better ...

I admit that index management must be dismal.

So I modify the underlying tables (Users, Identifiers, Capabilities, Children) to add UNIQUE CONSTRAINT and FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT. I had confused UNIQUE INDEX and UNIQUE CONSTRAINT...

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC."Users"("Id" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"UserName" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"DisplayName" VARCHAR(100),"RootId" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"TimeStamp" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "UniqueUserName" UNIQUE ("UserName"))
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC."Identifiers"("Id" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"UserId" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"TimeStamp" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "ForeignIdentifiersUsers" FOREIGN KEY ("UserId") REFERENCES "Users"("Id"))
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC."Children"("ChildId" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"ItemId" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"TimeStamp" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "UniqueChildItem" UNIQUE ("ChildId", "ItemId"),CONSTRAINT "ForeignChildrenItems" FOREIGN KEY ("ItemId") REFERENCES "Items"("Id"))
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC."Capabilities"("UserId" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"ItemId" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"CanAddChild" BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,"CanRename" BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,"IsReadOnly" BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,"IsVersionable" BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,"Loaded" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,"SyncMode" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,"TimeStamp" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "ForeignCapabilitiesUsers" FOREIGN KEY ("UserId") REFERENCES "Users"("Id"),CONSTRAINT "ForeignCapabilitiesItems" FOREIGN KEY ("ItemId") REFERENCES "Items"("Id"))
```

And I also added INDEX on the VIEW Item, Child and the VIEW allowing me to build the new name (ChildUri, IdentifierUri, ItemUri and Uri).

I did not know that we could put INDEX on VIEW...

```
CREATE INDEX "ItemIndex" ON "Item"("UserId", "Id")
CREATE INDEX "ChildUriIndex" ON "ChildUri"("Id","Parent")
CREATE INDEX "IdentifierUriIndex" ON "IdentifierUri"("Idx","Parent")
CREATE INDEX "ItemUriIndex" ON "ItemUri"("Id","Parent")
CREATE INDEX "UriIndex" ON "Uri"("Id","Parent")
CREATE INDEX "ChildIndex" ON "Child"("UserId", "Parent")
```

I kept the Indexes "TrashedIndex" and "MimeTypeIndex" on the Items table, these columns appearing in WHERE clauses

```
CREATE INDEX "TrashedIndex" ON PUBLIC."Items"("Trashed")
CREATE INDEX "MimeTypeIndex" ON PUBLIC."Items"("MimeType")
```

The "selectChild" request is now done in a few seconds, but I'm not sure of my indexes ... I think I have redundant or missing, or so I'm very lucky ...

Thanks again.

Edit:
After several performance tests, apparently only the CONSTRAINT UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY at the level of the underlying tables improves the performance, the INDEX on the VIEW does not improve the query, or so imperceptibly without a performance test tool.